# Retrieve a URI's "return code"?

Tags: c#, process, uri, protocols

I have the following problem:

I do know how to start a process and I do know how to use the [`System::Diagnostics::Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-class, but when I want to start a process by using its associated (and registered) URI protocol, I am unable to retrieve any information about the launched process.

I am using the following code:

```
public static int Main(string[] argv)
{
    Process p = Process.Start("myuri://some_arguments");

    while (!p.HasExited)
        Application.DoEvents();

    Console.WriteLine(p.ExitCode);
    Console.ReadKey(true);

    return 0;
}
```

My C# application fails on the 5th line *`while (!p.HasExited)`*, as the variable *`p`* is `null`.

---

I am now wondering: why is this the case? And most importantly:

**TL;DR:** ... how can I retrieve a URI Protocol's "exit/return code"?

---

**EDIT NO.1:** [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34831271/3902603) from [@ohw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2183486/ohw) is very useful - however, I cannot use the class [`Windows::System::Launcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher), as my target machine(s) are running on Windows7 and not on Windows8 or higher

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) says `Process.Start` will return `null` if no process can be started.

I don't think this is the correct way to invoke the URI's handler. You can check out `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` if you are targeting Windows 8/10.

To achieve this in earlier versions of Windows, you can always look up the registry to find out what the handler program is for the URI scheme, because the handler is registered under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` in the Windows registry. See [here](https://github.com/beothorn/URISchemeHandler/blob/master/src/main/java/uriSchemeHandler/WindowsURISchemeHandler.java) for an implementation in Java, and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx) for some official documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir :) The problem is -however- that I am not able to use the class in question, as it requires Windows8 _(the machine(s) I have to target are running on Windows7)_